# "No such table" on code-first EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 3.1.1 when table exists

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=visual-studio) article on how to work with Entity Framework Core and Sqlite. My objects are named differently and have different properties but that's about the only change I have made to the code given in the article.

I used migrations to create a database and a table in it. I opened the database using SQLiteStudio and can see the table "Tasks" is created there with the proper columns.

However I get the error "No such table: Tasks" when trying to save a new "Task" object in it.

Here is my code:

`Model.cs`

```
public class TaskContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlite("Data Source = TestDatabase.db");
}
```

`Task.cs`

```
public class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastExecutionDateTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ExecutionInterval { get; set; }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start.");

        using (var db = new TaskContext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Saving new task...");
            db.Add(new Task { TaskId=1, TaskName = "test", ExecutionInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10), LastExecutionDateTime = DateTime.Now });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End.");
    }
}
```

Just like the article said, I have included the Nuget Packages `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`, enabled migrations and did an initial migration (that's how the database got created). I have a folder "Migrations" and a table "__EFMigrationsHistory" in the database.

So I can't figure out why it would throw such an error instead of add a new record in the table.

Comment: Try `db.Tasks.Add(...)` instead of `db.Add(...)`!

Comment: Is visual studio finding `Data Source = TestDatabase.db` successfully?

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi, same error at same place.

Comment: @AlejandroH, how would I check that? I imagine it does, because it should throw an error if I point it to a database that does not exist.

Comment: Where `TestDatabase.db` file located ?!

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi, same directory as project.

Comment: please try the specific address of `TestDatabase.db` file in the connection string. I mean something like that `...UseSqlite(@"Data Source= C:\TestDatabase.db ")`.

replace `C:\TestDatabase.db` with your own address.

Comment: you can put a breakpoint here `protected override void OnConfiguring(` and read the values it returns when debugger hits the `}`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this certainly was retarded.

For some reason, migrations creates the database at the foot of your project. When debugging everything is deployed in a series of directories that start with "bin" and end in "netcoreappX.X".

Guess where a hardcoded relative path leads to?

Also you better guess there's ALSO a *.db file in that "netcoreapp" that is 0KB large.

Changing the path from relative to absolute fixes things.

Comment: Just to be clear, absolute path :    => options.UseSqlite("Data Source = c:\\Yourfolder\\TestDatabase.db")